# How to create file from byte array and send it to TelegramBot

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, telegram, telegram-bot

In Service1 I create a byte array and send it to Kafka.

In Service2 I receive a message from Service1, create a PDF file using this byte array and send it to TelegramBot, which sends it to the user.

**Service 1**

And that's how I send a byte array to Kafka

```
byte[] file = _pdfBuilder
.AddObject(o =>
{
o.HtmlContent = html;
})
.Convert();

var result = await producer.ProduceAsync(_producerTopic, new Message<Null, string>()
{
Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(file)
}, cancelToken.Token);
```

**Service 2**

That's how I tried to create PDF file and send it to Telegram Bot

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("FileName.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    foreach (var bt in bytes)
    {
        fs.WriteByte(bt);
    }

    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var document = new InputOnlineFile(fs, "file.pdf");
    await _client.SendDocumentAsync(id, document);
}
```

Or this

```
await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var doc = new InputOnlineFile(memoryStream, "file.pdf");
await _client.SendDocumentAsync(id, doc);
```

Or

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var doc = new InputOnlineFile(memoryStream, "file.pdf");
await _client.SendDocumentAsync(id, doc);
```

So the problem is: in a chat with Telegram Bot I receive an empty PDF file.

That's also how I used to create a file in the controller (the file wasn't empty)

```
 byte[] file = _pdfBuilder
                .AddObject(o =>
                {
                    o.HtmlContent = html;
                })
                .Convert();

 return File(file, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: When you save the PDF locally from the byte array is it a valid pdf(not corrupted)?

Comment: Try to save the data prepared for sending to a file and open this file using a PDF viewer.

Comment: You send pdf file to user? or channel chat?

Comment: What pdf size are you trying to send?

Comment: @DekuDesu, I use this service in kubertnetes cluster, so I can’t check it

Comment: @DekuDesu I have updated my question, please take a look

Comment: You send pdf flie as string? `Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(file)` and decode on service 2?

Comment: Unicode encoding and decoding breaks the pdf file

Comment: @Genusatplay, what should I use instead of Unicode? ASCII?

Comment: Yes, I decode string in Service 2 using 
`byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);`

Comment: @SimonElMansoury update answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode encoding and decoding breaks the pdf file.
If you need send file as string use Base64 convert

```
var byteArray = new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var encString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
var decBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encString);
//result: byte[9] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please take a look